# image change or disable on click

Tags: php

i have a image on my site that work as like button when some one click on it page will be refresh and add 1 in like box.now i want that after click on it once after adding 1 in like count box and page refresh image will be hide or link will remove.please help any one?
here is the button code

```
 <div class="code_large" style="margin-top:10px;">
 <img src="images/more_img_large.jpg"  hspace="5" align="absmiddle" />
  <span>
   <?php echo $value['love_it']; ?></span><span style=" line-height:30px; margin-left:55px;">
  <a href="index.php?option=com_shopsearch&task=loveit&shop_id=<?php echo $value['shop_id']; ?>">
  <img src="images/love_it.jpg" alt="Love it" width="106" name="loveit" id="Image9" height="28" onClick="multiclick();"  />
   </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<a <?php if(!isset($_GET['task']) || $_GET['task'] != "loveit"){?> href="index.php?option=com_shopsearch&task=loveit&shop_id=<?php echo $value['shop_id']; ?>" <?php } else{?>  href="javascript:void(0);"<?php }?>>
  <img src="images/love_it.jpg" alt="Love it" width="106" name="loveit" id="Image9" height="28" onClick="multiclick();"  />
  </a>
```

This will remove the href once the link is clicked and page reloaded.

Comment: i used this code but not work.here is the link of my site on that you can see love it button.i want to do it on my love it button.http://shoppingmore.com.hk/index.php?option=com_shopsearch&view=shopdetails&shop_id=139

Comment: Why in location bar shows http://shoppingmore.com.hk/index.php?option=com_shopsearch&view=shopdetails&shop_id=139 there is no task variable there...I guess some redirect is happening in inside your code

Comment: yes when you click it page will be reload.

Comment: @FarrukhZaman : There should be task=loveit in url. but it is not there, so it is redirecting from the page again i guess

Comment: i have make variable like this $_GET['task']="loveit".

Comment: but there is no link now.